# Powershell in NSIS and Components Page

Tags: powershell, components, nsis

1. I'm trying to run .ps1 for uninstalling windows apps on Win10 64.My problem is that i want to Detailprint every single command output but i only managed to print the last line's one. My code is similar to the powershell guide on nsis.sourceforge.
2. How i get the Instpage dialogs wrapped so no need to scroll horizontally or get them in a tooltip.
3. If its possible to insert icons in the three view components page, same as list view one..

Thank you

EDIT:

```
!insertmacro PsExec Psfile

${If} ${RunningX64}
    ${DisableX64FSRedirection}
${EndIf}

loop:
LineRead Psfile Line $R0
Push $R0
IntComp $R0 0 goto finish
Exectostack 'powershell "& ${PScommand}'
Pop $R0
Detailprint $R0
IntOp Line + 1
goto loop

finish:
  Pop $R0
 Detailprint "Finish uninstalling..."
!macroend

${If} ${RunningX64}
   ${EnableX64FSRedirection}
${EndIf}

!macroend
```

After in my .nsi i just use ${Psexec} "file.ps1"

(Im not sure about how to use the Lineread func, how to get the answer from it and transform it to Pscommand... or implementing the loop aswell... i've tried many changes but still not getting it.

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61801719/edit) and add the script you're having problems with :)

Comment: The code you posted does not even compile.

Comment: thnx, so constructive